# Getting Data from one app, and sending it to another app, using my app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am developing an app that exposes a Share Intent. When a user opens the Share menu from any app, he sees my app in the list.

Once the user selects my option, he gets his file encrypted, and he should be able to share it from within the app, all in one click.

Moreover, my app uses authentication for login.

Currently, I am able to expose my app activity as Share Intent. I am also able to select it from a file browser. But, when I select my app from the list, it directly goes to the activity, not to the authentication. I hope that is the way it should be, but I want it to go to the authentication first, once authenticated, then go to the Encrypt&Share activity. How do I do that?

Besides that, I am also getting the files URI that user has selected, through `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` but, when I try to print the URI, it gives me null pointer exception. I have used SEND_MULTIPLE as action in the manifest. What am I doing wrong here? Please Help.

The code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_encrypt_share);

        Intent intent = getIntent();        
        ArrayList<Uri> fileUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        System.err.print(fileUris);     
        for(Uri f: fileUris){
            Log.e("FileName:", f.getPath().toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to implement this feature by checking the scheme of the data. If the scheme is "file" we get the Path and pass it to the Share Intent, and if the scheme is "content" then we convert it to path using [this](https://gist.github.com/crackjack/5494970) and then send it to the Share Intent.

For the issue of checking authentication, it seems that we have to pass the data manually to the starting activity and again pass the data back when it is complete. It is the way to share data between activities in android.

I hope this information would help someone in future.

Regards.